Is there a difference between declaring a pointer and an array in C language?
I'm porting an old video-game emulator to Arduino MCUs environment. In the same time I'm performing a lot of refactoring to the C code 'cause it needs some cleaning and simplification.
Using C language, GCC cross-compilation from Debian 12 to an Arduino Nano ESP-32 (Espressif ESP32-S3 MCU). Using Visual Code but I don't think my question is OS or IDE-related. Due to compatibility with some Arduino's environment libraries I in fact use .cpp extensions files even if my code is pure C.
I use a simple uint8_t (aka char) array to store game cartridge ROM bytes. It's declared this way in header (.h) file:
extern uint8_t rom[8192];

And defined this way in corresponding .cpp
#define ROM_SIZE 8192

uint8_t rom[ROM_SIZE] = {0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x84, 0x02...

Until now everything was OK, working fine.
Then I decided to try running 16 kB programs. So I need to perform some small modifications on the virtual machine code, and of course change the size of my "rom" array and fill it with more bytes. As I wanted to be able to run either 8 or 16 kB ROMs I also changed the header file for more flexibility:
extern uint8_t *rom;

And corresponding .cpp
#define ROM_SIZE 16384

uint8_t rom[ROM_SIZE] = { ...

And now my program is still compiling / linking fine, but crashing the ESP32 when executed. And it's really crashing: RGB LED blinking crazy, no more bootloader available, I need to reset it to be able to access it again. It really looks like a SEG FAULT...
By just changing the declaration in the header file to:
extern uint8_t rom[];

Everything is OK.
So, my main question is:
What's the difference between declaring (not defining: only declaring) a variable as an array or as a pointer. In both case I don't use any malloc() but a static definition of the content in C code:
#define ROM_SIZE 16384

uint8_t rom[ROM_SIZE] = { ...

I've always thought that:
extern uint8_t *rom;
extern uint8_t rom[];

were doing the same thing. It's now obvious at least in this particular case it isn't but I can't understand why.
Any clue?

The difference when declaring an array and a pointer to the element type comes into play when the compiler is generating code to access the declared object.
For uint8_t rom[], the symbol rom is the address of the array and to access an element, an offset is added to rom.
For uint8_t *rom, the symbol rom is the address where an address is stored. The code first needs to load an address from rom and then add an offset. In other words, there's one more indirection involved. This is why code where declaration does not match definition will crash easily.

Thank you @Jens. I think I understand the difference between both. But why does this code compile and execute without crashing in this case:   `int simple_array[4] = { 3, 14, 15, 9};
int *simple_pointer;
int main (int argc, char **argv)
simple_pointer = simple_array;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
printf ("Using array variable: %d\n", simple_array[i]);
printf ("Using pointer variable: %d\n", simple_pointer[i]);
}
}`

That's because in an expression (not in a declaration, as you have specifically asked), an array "decays" to (is reinterpreted by the compiler as) a pointer to its first element. I'll wait for someone to point out that there is an exception when the array identifier is the operand of sizeof.
